# TextView cannot be converted to double

Tags: textview, android-edittext, razorpay

```
 try{
            String payment = editTextPayment.getText().toString();

            double total = Double.toString(editTextPayment);
            total = total * 100;
            options.put("amount", total);

    } catch (Exception e){

    }
```

Error

> error: incompatible types: TextView cannot be converted to double
> double total = Double.toString(editTextPayment);

Please help me to correct this

```
    try{
        String payment = editTextPayment.getText().toString();

        double total = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(editTextPayment));
        total = total * 100;
        options.put("amount", total);

    }catch (Exception e){

    }
```

Not recieving the total amount

Comment: `editText` is a _TextView_ and not a string. You need to do something like this:    
            String payment = editTextPayment.getText().toString();
            double total = Double.parseDouble(payment);

Comment: Still not working

Comment: that maybe your payment string is empty or null
        double total = Double.parseDouble(payment.isEmpty() ? "0" :  payment);